# How to delete a specific amount of columns randomly?

Tags: shell, awk

Using this range from 1 to 60, formatted in 6 lines and 10 columns.

```
01 02 03 04 05 06 07 08 09 10
11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20
21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30
31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 40
41 42 43 44 45 46 47 48 49 50
51 52 53 54 55 56 57 58 59 60
```

The command

```
awk -v n=6 -v p=2 ' BEGIN {srand()} rand() * n-- < p {p--; next} {print}' < file
```

deletes 2 lines of the 6 existing lines randomly.

How can I do the same with the columns? Delete a specific amount of columns randomly, (using awk, preferably).

Example:

**Delete 3 (or any number from 1 to 10) from any of the 10 columns.**

Comment: Asking for help with your homework is okay but you need to make a good faith effort to solve the problem yourself. Then show us your attempt at a solution and, hopefully, explain which part of your solution you believe is incorrect.